# How to change a mouse cursor image for all windows?

Tags: c++, linux, cursor, x11, xlib

I am trying to change a mouse cursor for the entire system (for each window on a display) with the help of XCursor and XInput2.


In the code below, the cursor changes. However, only for browser window =>

When I focus on other windows, the cursor is still default.

As I understand, `XTranslateCoordinates()` function has to return the window which is under the cursor and then I just `DefineCursor` for this window. It also does not work if I replace `XTranslateCoordinates` by  `XGetInputFocus(d, &w, &revert_to)`.

Probably I do not understand the way cursors are going to be changed on windows. Would be extremely glad for helping!

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
Display *display;
Window root_window;

display = XOpenDisplay(0);
root_window = XRootWindow(display, 0);

Cursor cursorDefault;
Cursor CursorClickR;
Cursor CursorClickL;

CreateCursor("1.png", cursorDefault, display);

unsigned char mask_bytes[(XI_LASTEVENT + 7) / 8] = {0}; /* must be zeroed! */
XISetMask(mask_bytes, XI_RawMotion);

XIEventMask evmasks[1];
evmasks[0].deviceid = XIAllMasterDevices;
evmasks[0].mask_len = sizeof(mask_bytes);
evmasks[0].mask = mask_bytes;
XISelectEvents(display, root_window, evmasks, 1);

XEvent xevent;
while (1)
{
    XNextEvent(display, &xevent);
    XGetEventData(display, &xevent.xcookie);

    Window root_return, child_return;
    int root_x_return, root_y_return;
    int win_x_return, win_y_return;
    unsigned int mask_return;

    XQueryPointer(display, root_window, &root_return, &child_return,
                  &root_x_return, &root_y_return,
                  &win_x_return, &win_y_return,
                  &mask_return);

    int local_x, local_y;
    XTranslateCoordinates(display, root_window, child_return,
                          root_x_return, root_y_return,
                          &local_x, &local_y, &child_return);

    if (child_return)
        XDefineCursor(display, child_return, cursorDefault);
}

XCloseDisplay(display);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you move to another window, that program will select its own cursor. That's the way it works. This reminds me of the old question of what happens when two programs both try to be always-on-top. Just doesn't work,

Comment: Yes and that is why I used the XGetInputFocus function in order to get the window which is focused in order to change the cursor for this particular window, but it did not work